# Mantain scrollable content position on width change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here's my problem: Im working on a layout the has a sidebar that expands on mouse enter and minimizes to original size on mouse leave, and handling this resize with some css transitions. The sidebar has scroll-y so i can scroll the content on the sidebar.

Everything ok so far, but here's the big problem im facing: On the resize of the sidebar, the content that is displayed shifts from original position, because of the new dimension that supports more content, the scrollable height decreases as you expand the sidebar, and that causes the content to "move away" from it's original position and i don't want that, i want the content to stay the same position (distance from top, for example) it was before the resize.

I checked the scrollTop value with JQuery and it does not changes, the only thing that varies is the scrollHeight property. Then i tried to grab the scrolled percentage based on the scrollHeight, so i could always keep the scroll on the same percentage of its total scrollHeight but it did not seem to work also.

I made a fiddle that can picture the entire problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/cachola/8Uvz8/2/

CSS:

```
html,body{height:100%;width:100%;}
body{
    background: rgb(232,233,231);
    overflow:hidden;
}
aside{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;      
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease;
   -moz-transition:all .5s ease;
     -o-transition:all .5s ease;
        transition:all .5s ease;    
    height:100%;
    width:220px;
    background: rgb(188,182,155);
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
aside:hover{
    width:520px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <aside>
        <h1>1.Example</h1>
        <p>Federal prosecutors are nearing criminal charges against some of the world’s biggest banks, according to lawyers briefed on the matter, a development that could produce the first guilty plea from a major bank in more than two decades.</p>
        <h1>2.Example</h1>
        <p>In doing so, prosecutors are confronting the popular belief that Wall Street institutions have grown so important to the economy that they cannot be charged. A lack of criminal prosecutions of banks and their leaders fueled a public outcry over the perception that Wall Street giants are “too big to jail.”

Addressing those concerns, prosecutors in Washington and New York have met with regulators about how to criminally punish banks without putting them out of business and damaging the economy, interviews with lawyers and records reviewed by The New York Times show.</p>
        <h1>3.Example</h1>
        <p>In doing so, prosecutors are confronting the popular belief that Wall Street institutions have grown so important to the economy that they cannot be charged. A lack of criminal prosecutions of banks and their leaders fueled a public outcry over the perception that Wall Street giants are “too big to jail.”

Addressing those concerns, prosecutors in Washington and New York have met with regulators about how to criminally punish banks without putting them out of business and damaging the economy, interviews with lawyers and records reviewed by The New York Times show.
        In doing so, prosecutors are confronting the popular belief that Wall Street institutions have grown so important to the economy that they cannot be charged. A lack of criminal prosecutions of banks and their leaders fueled a public outcry over the perception that Wall Street giants are “too big to jail.”

Addressing those concerns, prosecutors in Washington and New York have met with regulators about how to criminally punish banks without putting them out of business and damaging the economy, interviews with lawyers and records reviewed by The New York Times show.</p>
    </aside>
</body>
```

Comment: this is a really difficult problem to solve since you're changing the width of the content. Off the top of my head, maybe you could insert some sort of anchor with an ID (based on the current position), then scroll to it once the width change is complete?

Comment: So I did something you might find interesting, though it won't entirely solve your problem. This will figure out the percentage of the scroll height from where you were before the re-size and then adjust the scroll height to the same percentage of the new scroll height. Unfortunately font widths are rather unpredictable so it's not perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/8Uvz8/6/

Comment: user1506980 that was the same solution i came up with, but the problem seems to be the text line breaking that makes it anaccurate :/ but thanks anyway!
pennstatephil, but where would this anchor be positioned? and how (absolute, fixed, relative)? i think the solution might be that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 Reputation so I can't make a comment, so instead I have to ask it here. Are you looking for the content to keep its current layout after the containing div grows? And if that is what you are looking for, you could put the div with the contents inside of a containing div and have the containing div grow. If that isn't what you are looking for could you please elaborate?

Comment: But making the containing div grow would not cause the same effect to the text content?
I came across this fiddle last night that could illustrate better what im trying to achieve:
The guy does it with the window resize, wich is easier because of the resize event.
http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/RmNap/

Comment: Anyone got something else? Still on that issue :/